# Question concerning efficiency in calculated array indices and repeated references to a specific array value

Tags: javascript

In trying to minimize the time it takes a JavaScript function to process, please consider this set up.  In the function is a loop that operates on an array of similar objects.  The index of the array is `[4 + loop counter]` and there are several references to `array[4+i][various property names]`, such as `a[4+i].x`, `a[4+i].y`, `a[4+i].z` in each loop iteration.

Is it okay to keep calculating `4+i` several times within each loop iteration, or would efficiency be gained by declaring a variable at the top of the loop to hold the value of `4+i` and use that variable as the index, or declare a variable to be a reference to the `a[4+i]` object?  Is it more work for the browser to declare a new variable or to add `4+i` ten times? Does the browser work each time to find `a[n]` such that, if one needs to use the object in `a[n]` multiple times per loop iteration, it would be better to set `x = a[n]` and just reference `x.property_names` ten times?

Thank you for considering my very novice question.

Comment: just take the incremented index or better an object refence to the element.

Comment: 1) *Benchmark it.* That’ll tell you for sure which variation is more performant in your case. 2) It doesn’t matter. Either way will be plenty fast enough for real world scenarios. Write readable code first and foremost.

Comment: The difference will probably be tiny, but set `x = a[n]` anyway because it’s easier to read. Then benchmark it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the browser work each time to find `a[n]` such that, if one needs to use the object in `a[n]` multiple times per loop iteration, it would be better to set `x = a[n]` and just reference `x.property_names` ten times?

Yes. Although the JavaScript engine may be able to optimize away the repeated `a[4+i]` work, it also might not be able to, depending on what your code is doing. In contrast, creating a local variable to store the reference in is very, very little work.

Subjectively, it's also probably clearer to the reader and more maintainable to do `x = a[4+i]` once and then use `x`.

That said, the best way to know the answer to this question in your specific situation is to do it and see if there's an improvement.

Comment: Thank you.  I cannot visibly see a difference in use, either way, but was interested in the best way to code to 'help' the browser work efficiently; and this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet runs for a bit more than half minutes...

```js
function m(f){
  const t=[Date.now()];
  const s=[];
  for(let r=0;r<10;r++){
    s.push(f());
    t.push(Date.now());
  }
  for(let i=0;i<t.length-1;i++)
    t[i]=t[i+1]-t[i];
  t.pop();
  t.sort((a,b)=>a-b);
  t.pop();
  t.pop();
  return t.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
}

const times=1000;
const bignumber=100000;
const bigarray=new Array(bignumber);
for(let i=0;i<bignumber;i++)
  bigarray[i]={x:Math.random(),y:Math.random(),z:Math.random()};
for(let i=0;i<4;i++)
  bigarray.push(bigarray[i]);

console.log("idx",m(function(){
  let sum=0;
  for(let r=0;r<times;r++)
    for(let i=0;i<bignumber;i++)
      sum+=bigarray[i].x+bigarray[i].y+bigarray[i].z;
  return sum;
}));

console.log("idx+4",m(function(){
  let sum=0;
  for(let r=0;r<times;r++)
    for(let i=0;i<bignumber;i++)
      sum+=bigarray[i+4].x+bigarray[i+4].y+bigarray[i+4].z;
  return sum;
}));

console.log("item",m(function(){
  let sum=0;
  for(let r=0;r<times;r++)
    for(let i=0;i<bignumber;i++){
      let item=bigarray[i];
      sum+=item.x+item.y+item.z;
    }
  return sum;
}));

console.log("item+4",m(function(){
  let sum=0;
  for(let r=0;r<times;r++)
    for(let i=0;i<bignumber;i++){
      let item=bigarray[i+4];
      sum+=item.x+item.y+item.z;
    }
  return sum;
}));
```

... and produces output like

> ```
> idx 2398
> idx+4 2788
> item 2252
> item+4 2303
> ```

for me on Chrome. The numbers are runtime in milliseconds of 8 runs (8 best out of 10).

Where

- `idx` is `bigarray[b].x+bigarray[b].y+bigarray[b].z`, repeated access to the same element with a named index (`i`)
- `idx+4` is `bigarray[i+4].x+bigarray[i+4].y+bigarray[i+4].z`, repeated access to the same element with a calculated index (`i+4`)
- `item` is `item.x+item.y+item.z`, so an array element was stored in a variable
- `item+4` is `item.x+item.y+item.z` too, just the array element was picked from `i+4`

Your question is very visibly the outlier here. Repeated access to an element with a "fixed" index (`idx` case) is already a bit slower than getting out the element into a variable (`item` and `item+4` cases, where `+4` is the slower one of course, that addition is executed 800 million times after all). But the 3 times repeated access to an element with a calculated index (`idx+4` case) is 15-20+% slower than any of the others.

Here the array is so small that it fits into the L3 cache. If you "move" a couple `0`-s from `times` to `bignumber`, the overall difference decreases to 10-15%, and anything else than `idx+4` performs practically the same.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make this example.  It is interesting to see that `idx` is slower than `item`.  Until yesterday, I hadn't thought about what the browser or processor does to get the data held in a particular index of an array.  So, it is less work to create a local variable to store the value of an array at a specific index than to repeatedly reference it as`a[i]` because that is a little work each time.  Your results seem to make intuitive sense; however, i cannot match them in Firefox, but my machine is over ten years, dual core, 2GB RAM.

Comment: If I run it using `bignumber=100000`, each takes around 13,500ms and the results never makes sense, such as `item` is the slowest but all are about the same.  If I run it using `bignumber=25000`, then `idx` is consistently the slowest at around 1925ms and `item` is the quickest at about 1675ms and `idx+4` and `item+4` are about equal at 1735ms.  The values fluctuate but are relatively roughly the same. Something else must be taking place on my old machine to generate these results.  Regardless, what you provided makes sense as a sound coding practice in general.

Comment: Perhaps, it is a matter of having to understand how the browser/JS interpreter works to best know how to write code to 'help' it optimize its instructions to the hardware. But why `idx+4` would be faster than `idx`, I cannot speculate otherwise.

Comment: @Gary a ten years old CPU with 2 cores probably has a small cache, and it probably uses slower memory (presumably DDR3). You can look up some details on Wikipedia, like in this list of Intel processors: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_microprocessors - there is a "see also" section at the bottom where you can find links to more detailed tables, and to lists of processors from other manufacturers.